# Passing data between two view controllers in a tab controller

Tags: ios, swift

I have a tab bar controller which contains two view controllers. I want to pass the data from the first view controller to the second one. I'm currently using the singleton approach:

```
class Items {
    static let shared = Items()
    var array = [Item]()
}
```

The first view controller is responsible for populating the shared array.

```
class FirstiewController: UIViewController {
   func appendElement() {
       let newItem = Item()
       Items.shared.array.append(newItem)
   }
}
```

The second view controller should retrieve the array every time the view is presented on screen.

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

    internal var items: [Item] = []

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        items = Items.shared.array
    }
}
```

This is not ideal, for performance reasons I would like to only fetch when a new value is added to the array. How can we add a listener so that we fetch only when the app appends a new element to the array?

Comment: Maybe you can use getter & setter for items array in second View controller . internal var items: [Item] { get { return Items.shared.array } set { Items.shared.array = newValue } }

Comment: see -> https://github.com/cesarferreira/SwiftEventBus or you can use NotificationCenter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Using Delegate Pattern

First create protocol for your `Items` class

```
protocol ItemsDelegate {
    func newItemAdded()
}
```

then in `Items` class create variable for your delegate and call method on delegate when new value of your `array` did set

```
class Items {

    var delegate: ItemsDelegate?

    static let shared = Items()
    var array = [Item]() {
        didSet {
           delegate?.newItemAdded()
        }
    }

}
```

then in `viewDidLoad` set delegate of singleton as `self`

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    ...
    Items.shared.delegate = self
}
```

then implement this protocol to your ViewController and declare what should happen when new item is added

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController, ItemsDelegate {
    ...
    func newItemAdded() {
        items = Items.shared.array
    }
    ...
}
```